# How to update preview when custom setting changed in my custom widget

Tags: customization, widgets

I decided to override one widget there and decided to add some custom settings for it.

The appearance of the widget is controlled by JavaScript function (I use slick slider there, which is suppose to be configurable through the widget settings)

So here is the widget class: (as example from here http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget/)

```
 <?php

// Creating the widget
class wpb_widget extends WP_Widget
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
        // Base ID of your widget
        'wpb_widget',

        // Widget name will appear in UI
        __('WPBeginner Widget', 'wpb_widget_domain'),

        // Widget description
        array(
        'description' => __( 'Sample widget based on WPBeginner Tutorial', 'wpb_widget_domain' ),
        'customize_selective_refresh' => true,
        )
            );


             // Enqueue style if widget is active (appears in a sidebar) or if in Customizer preview.
        if ( is_active_widget( false, false, $this->id_base ) || is_customize_preview() ) {
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ) );
        }
    }

// Creating widget front-end

    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );

        // before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if (! empty( $title )) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
        }

        // This is where you run the code and display the output
        echo __( 'Hello, World!', 'wpb_widget_domain' );
        echo("<div id='customId'>TEST</div>");
        echo $args['after_widget'];

    }

// Widget Backend 
    public function form($instance)
    {
        if (isset( $instance[ 'title' ] )) {
            $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
        } else {
            $title = __( 'New title', 'wpb_widget_domain' );
        }
        // Widget admin form
        ?>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" 
            id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" 
            name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" 
            type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" 
        />
    </p>
<?php

}

public function enqueue_scripts() {

    $randomParameter =  random_int(1, 100);

    $dataToBePassed = array(
        'someParameter' => $randomParameter
    );

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'customjs',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/customwidget.js',
        array( 'jquery','customize-preview' ),
        '',
        true
    );

    wp_localize_script('customjs', 'settings', $dataToBePassed);
}


    // Updating widget replacing old instances with new
    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
    {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
        return $instance;
    }
} // Class wpb_widget ends here
```

here is example of binded js:

```
(function ($) {
    console.log("custom widget js init");

    var configureCustomWidget = function(){
        var me = this,
            conf = settings || {someParameter:5};

        $('#customId').html("<h1>"+conf.someParameter+"</h1>");
    }

    configureCustomWidget();

    // Short-circuit selective refresh events if not in customizer preview or pre-4.5.
    if ('undefined' === typeof wp || !wp.customize || !wp.customize.selectiveRefresh) {
        return;
    }

    // Re-load widgets when a partial is rendered.
    wp.customize.selectiveRefresh.bind('partial-content-rendered', function (placement) {
        debugger;
    });

    // Refresh a moved partial containing 
    wp.customize.selectiveRefresh.bind('partial-content-moved', function (placement) {
        debugger;
    });

})(jQuery);
```

On preview everything is fine with that, but the problem is that even though I done as it recommended [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/03/22/implementing-selective-refresh-support-for-widgets/) it just didn't work out because of at the moment of when script initialized for some reason `wp.customize.selectiveRefresh` is undefined.

Like here:
[image]

So any ideas of how I can toggle binded widget JavaScript on setting change?

P.S.

It's just a simplified example, there will be an additional options and I want to change, let say just text fields, named 'customId'. And on change I want it to make changes in HTML, like changing some style stuff or etc.

**UPD**:

**(story)**

First of all, I am creating the theme for a WordPress site.

This theme should contain some widgets.

One of the widgets is supposed to be extended from `woocommerce` product category lists. But the default product category list got the output just like a simple bulleted list with description and photo.

So, to make it fancier I decided to make it look like a slider. I decided to use one little JavaScript library for that, named [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

And the thing is, it really flexible and could be configured, as example, like this:

```
$('.myCustomSlider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true
});
```

And so, I decided to add to my widget options like you can see in the JavaScript object here, so `Slides to show`, `Slides to scroll` etc.

I was thinking that on theme customization screen it would be nice, when the user changes those options value and could see the how changes happen.

**(implementation)**

To not make this question really wide - [full code is here](https://gist.github.com/dylanklbld/7af135bcb679b97a6a5f6a795efc6b71)

So, first of all, in my theme, I overrode the default `product category` widget, changes were simple - just added custom settings into already exists & called slider script at the hook:

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        $extraSettings = array(
          'slidesCount'  => array(
              'type'  => 'number',
              'step'  => 1,
              'min'   => 1,
              'max'   => '',
              'std'   => 3,
              'label' => __( 'Slides count per page', 'woocommerce' ),
          )
        );

        parent::__construct();

        $this->settings = array_merge($this->settings, $extraSettings);

         // To call script for the slider.
         if ( is_active_widget( false, false, $this->id_base ) || is_customize_preview() ) {
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ) );
        }
    }
```

also, changed `<ul>` to `<div class="product-categories slider">` like that

```
echo '<div class="product-categories slider">';

wp_list_categories( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', $list_args ) );

echo '</div>';
```

I also overrode the widget's default walker (but just made changes in outputting `html` stuff) like  `<li>` to `<div class='slide'>`

And then there is my custom JavaScript with bind to events mentioned [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/03/22/implementing-selective-refresh-support-for-widgets/).

It works one when loaded. But when I change something it's just no any reaction there. And the reason is the same as I described above -`wp.customize.selectiveRefresh` is not defined.

But the main question is - how to update client part after my custom/overridden widget settings are updated?

Hope it made some things clear :)

Comment: there are so many missing pieces here, I have no idea what is that you are asking. please edit the question, focus on the problem in the start of it, what is it you are trying to do and failing, than give the background. What is that JS, how is it loaded, for what and when are some of the things I could not understand now

Comment: @MarkKaplun oh, okay, will update it

Comment: @MarkKaplun took more time than I tought i would to describe it

Answer (score 1):

As a role of thumb, you should not extend widgets that you do not control unless their author specifically gave guidance on how to do that. Extending is somewhat easier on the PHP side, but it is hard(er) to extend UI with JS if facilities were not put in place in advance.

A safer (at least from ease of development perspective) way is to "fork" the widget code. Take the code, make whatever modification you need to it, and call the widget a new name, or depending on your needs you can override the "official" name  (unregister the original, and register yours under the same handle).

This will mean that with each new version of WC you will need to make sure that you do not need to update your code to reflect a change in the "original" widget, but most likely you would have needed to do that even if you were just "extending".

Comment: well, the thing is, they not really use any js in that. I'd like to fork but even with simple example (added first in the question) I can't make it to stick with my custom js

Comment: For it to work you will need to know the IDs of the elements, you will need to handle the `widget_update` and `widget_added` (IIRC the names) events the customizer raises when widget are add/updated to maybe re-register your handlers. It is doable, it is not very well documented. Your specific problem comes from not initializing your JS and the right time (i.e. probably too early) or trying to use it on the widgets admin window. widget admin window will require some code that is at least somewhat different than the customizer code as things operate a little differently there.

Comment: hmm, interesting, +1 for now, will try to use it

Comment: btw is it even good practice? I mean, how normally ppl implement stuff like that? I never worked with wordpress before and got poor php experience

Comment: poor practice? in what regard?

Comment: wellp, I am .net developer. thats what I do for living. last time I writed in php - in universty I made some simple php + mysql webgallery

Comment: wellp, simply adding smth like this in js not worked `$(document).on('widget-updated', function(event, widget){ debugger });`

Comment: it is not great but unlike .net applications (talking out of ignorance and assumptions on the kind of apps built with that tech)  the "ground" is likely to shift faster especially with plugins (wordpress core is much more stable), therefor having more control over your code is an asset IMHO. If there was an official API which the author would have been committed to support extending might have made more sense. Part of the problem is that on JS side WP core is full of ad-hoc solutions, maybe if they move to react/vue/whatever it will be easier to extend things on the UI side

Comment: as I said it is not very easy ;) but without knowing where exactly you add you JS it is hard to guess why it is not triggered

Comment: I have some code that looks like `jQuery(document).on('widget-added widget-updated'....` which should work, so again it is something with how you add the JS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66823/discussion-between-danil-gholtsman-and-mark-kaplun).